# How to cancel a server side streaming gRPC call from client side in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, grpc, grpc-node

I have a gRPC server that streams data for an indefinite amount of time. It spawns a child process that retrieves some hardware resources stats.

What I want is to cancel the gRPC call from the client so that I can kill the spawned process.
Another solution would be a way to detect on the server when the client disconnects so that I can kill the process.

I am using grpc-node for both the client and the server.

I can't seem to figure out how to do this yet...

Comment: Thinking out loud (in writing) here - The RPCs are sent over TCP so I'm assuming the underlying mechanism will ensure that a packet has been received by a client or not given the ACK messages. If the client has disconnected then the TCP connection has terminated.  gRPC is something implemented at the application layer.

Comment: I understand that, but I assume there is a way to do this from the grpc-node package.

Answer (score 6):

Found the answer here: https://grpc.github.io/grpc/node/grpc-ClientReadableStream.html
Apparently I was using .close instead of .cancel

### On Server

```js
call.on('cancelled', () => {
    process.kill();
    console.log('cancelled')
});
```

### On Client

```js
const client = package.runner.Runner(host, grpc.credentials.createInsecure());
const call = client.YourService()
call.on('data', (data) => { console.log(data) })
call.cancel()
```

Comment: According to the documentation "cancel()" will cancel the ongoing call. In a stream, the server will send multiple messages back to the client. This means the callback function on your client may handle the first of those messages and then cancel the stream. This means any in-flight messages will be lost.

Comment: Yes, that is fine. I don't mind.